# Folder .INBOX in mail folder cpanel

Tags: email

i've a website the consume a lot of space 
my hoster propose for me to delete the content of the folder **.INBOX** 
i just want to confirm if it is save to delete the content? and what it contains

Answer (score 1):

The name suggests that it is some form of email mailbox. If the hosting provider that you use for your web site also handles email for you, they may simply be suggesting you clean out your mailbox.